# How to upload file to Asmx Web Service action

Tags: c#, web-services, http, asmx

This is sort of a very beginner question but I am not familiar with how to use HttpContext.Current.Request.Files

Lets pretend my webService Url is:

```
http://127.0.0.1/iisEntry/myApi.asmx
```

Can someone please spin up some quick code on how to upload a file to the following web method?

```
public void AddDocument(String title)
{            
    var action = new AddDocumentAction
                     {
                         File = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0],
                         DocumentTitle = title
                     }
    processor.Process(action);
}
```

Comment: Spin up Google and do a search...  A quick search revealed this link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937786/file-upload-via-webservice-in-c-sharp-with-jquery

Comment: That is in uploading the file with jquery... I want to know how to do it with C#

Answer (score 2):

HttpContext.Current.Request.Files contains files uploaded with POST request with "multipart/form-data" encoding type. ASMX web service could handle only XML/SOAP based requests, so you will not be able to upload files this way.

Options are:

- Add byte[] parameter to you web service method and [enable MTOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa529330.aspx) to handle large files.
- Add separate non-asmx handler (ASP.NET MVC Controller/Action with HttpPostedFileBase) to receive files.